# Custom font on finish page not working

Tags: nsis

I have code like this

```
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_TITLE_3LINES
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW WelcomeAndFinishPageShow
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH


Function WelcomeAndFinishPageShow
   FindWindow $1 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
   GetDlgItem $R0 $1 1201
   CreateFont $R1 $(^Font) 10 600
   SendMessage $R0 ${WM_SETFONT} $R1 0
FunctionEnd
```

But some how on finish page I am not seeing the changed font size.

Any ideas where I am doing wrong?

Comment: This script worked well on Welcome page but not on Finish Page I am going to try the below answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you should do is check $R0, if it is 0 then GetDlgItem did not find the label (Those IDs might not be totally stable, different MUI settings might change the order in which controls are created)

If you are using MUI2 there are some (under-documented) variables you can use:

```
Function WelcomeAndFinishPageShow
   CreateFont $R1 "Comic Sans MS" 10 600
   SendMessage $mui.WelcomePage.Title ${WM_SETFONT} $R1 0
   SendMessage $mui.FinishPage.Title ${WM_SETFONT} $R1 0
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: I am using electron builder, it generates a NSH structure little different with default of NSIS but it still uses default pages like Finish page. I tried to use your code but get error: $mui.FinishPage is not defined. Do you have any other solutions to change text of title by using handle?

Comment: @LeoVo Sounds like it might be using MUI v1 and not v2? v1 does not have these variables, you need a different approach.

Comment: no, i am using MUI 2, I tried to use $mui.FinishPage but get warning about this variable is not defined. But if I defined a variable mui.FinishPage, electron builder script said this variable is already defined. I believe electron builder redefine order of NSIS script. I think I need another solution to get right handle of Finish page